# Loading Website Problem, It keeps repeating when i go to different html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div#load, it is use as loading screen for the website starting from 0% - 100%. When it reach to 100% it adds a classlist to different div for animation purposes. I have the div#load inside my index.html and about.html. The problem I have is that when I go to about.html the number starts over from 0% and counts to 100% again and when I return to index.html it also starts from 0% to 100%.

I'm send sending the code here of my div#load and my JS.

```
<div id="load">
    <div id="load-wrapper">
        <div id="load-no">0</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function counter(){
    const counts = setInterval(function(){
        var load_no = document.getElementById('load-no'),
            number = parseInt(load_no.textContent);
        /* const load = document.getElementById('load');
        const ev_logo = document.getElementById('ev-logo');
        const nav_a_select = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-a');
        const fb_icon = document.querySelector('.fb-icon')
        const github_icon = document.querySelector('.github-icon')
        const line_h = document.querySelector('.line-h');
        const line_v = document.querySelector('.line-v');
        const copyright_icon = document.querySelector('.copyright-icon');
        const year = document.querySelector('.year');
        const name = document.querySelector('.name'); */
        load_no.textContent = (++number).toString();/* 
        const earl_villarias = document.querySelector('.earl-villarias')
        const slogan_text = document.querySelector('.slogan-text')
        const slogan_line_select = document.querySelectorAll('.slogan-line') */

        if (load_no.textContent==100){
            clearInterval(counts);
            /* load.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
            load_no.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, -110%, 0px)';
            ev_logo.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)';
            fb_icon.classList.add('fb-icon-s')
            github_icon.classList.add('github-icon-s')
            line_h.classList.add('line-expand-h')
            line_v.classList.add('line-expand-v')
            copyright_icon.classList.add('icon-year-s')
            year.classList.add('icon-year-s')
            name.classList.add('name-s')
            for (const nav_a of nav_a_select) {
                nav_a.classList.add('s-d')
            }
            earl_villarias.classList.add('name-show')
            slogan_text.classList.add('slogan-show')
            for (const slogan_line of slogan_line_select) {
                slogan_line.classList.add('slogan-line-expand')
            }
            load_no.textContent = number; */
        }
    })
}
counter();
```

What I am trying to aim is that when I go to about.html it wont load again but the classlist that was added is already there and when I return back to index.html it won't load from 0% to 100% again.

I am a newbie in JS and I'm trying to solve this problem for hours already. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Save the current percentage in local storage. Then when you go to a different page it can get the percentasge from local storage and start the progress reporter from there.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```js
function counter() {
    const counts = setInterval(function() {
        var load_no = document.getElementById('load-no');
        var number = parseInt(load_no.textContent);

        load_no.textContent = (++number).toString();

        if (load_no.textContent === '100') {
            clearInterval(counts);

            // Add your animations and transformations here
            const load = document.getElementById('load');
            const ev_logo = document.getElementById('ev-logo');
            const nav_a_select = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-a');
            const fb_icon = document.querySelector('.fb-icon');
            const github_icon = document.querySelector('.github-icon');
            const line_h = document.querySelector('.line-h');
            const line_v = document.querySelector('.line-v');
            const copyright_icon = document.querySelector('.copyright-icon');
            const year = document.querySelector('.year');
            const name = document.querySelector('.name');
            const earl_villarias = document.querySelector('.earl-villarias');
            const slogan_text = document.querySelector('.slogan-text');
            const slogan_line_select = document.querySelectorAll('.slogan-line');

            // Perform the necessary animations and transformations here

            load_no.textContent = number;
        }
    }, 30); // Set the time interval (in milliseconds), you can adjust this value for the desired speed
}

counter();
```

```html
<div id="load">
    <div id="load-wrapper">
        <div id="load-no">0</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work evertime i go to about.html. It still loads from 0% - 100%